# parse JavaScript object to render highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to parse the following JavaScript object to fill a [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) grouped chart. I am using python flask framework here but looks like parsing this would be best done if I do it all in JavaScript. Unfortunately Im very new to JavaScript and not sure how to proceed to parse this correctly.

To add to this im looking to get the following arrays

action_count, action_list as well as find a way to pass the created_month and year. Probably would have to combine these two things since its two different components in this object.

here is JSFiddle of what im looking to achieve.  jsfiddle.net/4bpjw0uq/6

```
# JSON Object I am trying to Parse.
 {
  "api_response": {
    "total_counts": [
      {
        "created_month": 2, 
        "created_year": 2017, 
        "action_counts": [
          0, 
          16, 
          8, 
          0, 
        ], 
        "action_list": [
          "action 1", 
          "action 2", 
          "action 3", 
          "action 4", 
        ], 
        "total_monthly_actions": 27
      }, 
      {
        "created_month": 3, 
        "created_year": 2017, 
        "action_counts": [
          0, 
          53, 
          50, 
          6, 
        ], 
        "action_list": [
            "action 1", 
            "action 2", 
            "action 3", 
            "action 4"
        ], 
        "total_monthly_actions": 154
      },       
    ], 
    "total_installations": 527
  }
}
```

Here is the highcharts example

```
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <script>


            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Actions'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        '2-17',
                        '3-17',
                        '4-17',
                    ],
                    crosshair: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'action 1',
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]

                }, {
                    name: 'action 2',
                    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4]

                }, {
                    name: 'action 3',
                    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4]

                }, {
                    name: 'action 4',
                    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7]

                }]
            });

        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Take care when spelling `JavaScript` to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this will work](https://jsfiddle.net/cyejL2uf/):

```
const api =  {
  "api_response": {
    "total_counts": [
      {
        "created_month": 2, 
        "created_year": 2017, 
        "action_counts": [
          0, 
          16, 
          8, 
          0, 
        ], 
        "action_list": [
          "action 1", 
          "action 2", 
          "action 3", 
          "action 4", 
        ], 
        "total_monthly_actions": 27
      }, 
      {
        "created_month": 3, 
        "created_year": 2017, 
        "action_counts": [
          0, 
          53, 
          50, 
          6, 
        ], 
        "action_list": [
            "action 1", 
            "action 2", 
            "action 3", 
            "action 4"
        ], 
        "total_monthly_actions": 154
      },       
    ], 
    "total_installations": 527
  }
};

const createHighChartData = (apiResponse) => {
  let series = [];
  const totalCounts = apiResponse.api_response.total_counts;
  //console.log(apiResponse.api_response.total_counts);

  let temp = []
  totalCounts.map((counts) => {
    //console.log(counts.action_counts);
    const actionCounts = counts.action_counts;
    actionCounts.map((action, i) => {
      //console.log(action, i);
      if (temp[i]){
       temp[i].push(action);
      } else {
        temp.push([action])
      }
    })
  })
  //console.log(temp);

  temp.map((dp, i) => {
    series.push({
      name: "Action " + (i + 1),
      data: dp
    })
  })

  console.log(series);
  return series
}

createHighChartData(api);
```

Comment: First off thanks so much for your help. To share more insight on on the grouping and how im trying to build the chart. if you look at the JSON object each month has two arrays action_count and action_list for every month im trying give the action list with the count

Comment: I also created this jsfiddle to show what i'm trying to do as it might be a bit difficult to explain http://jsfiddle.net/4bpjw0uq/3/

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt make much sense either, action 4 data is [42.4, 33.2, 34]. You dont have those values anywhere in the response

Comment: the numbers you see would be coming from the JSON objects 'action_counts' this would be the data in the chart. And the name would be the JSON objects 'action_list'. Sorry I confused you, i just left those numbers in as they were provided in some highcharts example i didn't change.

Comment: Let me update the jsfiddle example to be more clear.

Comment: This jsfiddle should be more useful for you http://jsfiddle.net/4bpjw0uq/6/

Comment: Well since I am much more in my element with python than JavaScript I have been trying to use python logic via Jinja2 in the JavaScript section to render this chart. Mainly trying to do some loop around the name and data series of the chart. The more I tried that the more I have become aware that is will most likely have to be handled using pure JavaScript so I have been throwing lots of random ideas at it that is getting me no where fast.

Comment: Well I can see this is doing exactly what I asked from the JS Console. Im just trying to figure out how this will fill the chart how do I call this ? I see it works but as I mentioned im new to JS and not sure how to call this from highcharts ?

Comment: `series: createHighChartData(api)`

Comment: Thanks You! Thank You! Thank You. I cant thank you enough for this help. I really appreciate your help.